# Extjs can't find resource

Tags: javascript, eclipse, tomcat, extjs

I deployed this project on Tomcat but when I tried to access from the webpage, the resources for ...ext-all.css and ...ext-debug.js could not be found. From eclipse, the project directory seems correct. Why can't these files be found?

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxOc9.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2GEn.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see the tomcat directory structure to be sure that this is the problem, but that index.html page is looking for a webapp in your tomcat webapp directory named: `ext-4.2.1.833`

In other words, it is expecting something like this:

```
+ tomcat
|-- bin
|-- conf
|-- lib
|-- logs
|-+ webapps
  |- ext-4.2.1.833
  |- HelloWorldApp (or whatever you called your new app)
  |- manager
  |- ROOT
```

Is that how you have it set-up?